# Default date in datetimepicker in visual studio

Tags: vb.net, winforms, ms-access

If the user selects the date in the DateTimePicker, it only picks up the date, which is what I need. However, if the user doesn't select any date and leaves the DateTimePicker as today's date, it shows date + time. The data is stored in an Access database. I want to store the date only in the Access store when the user leaves the DateTimePicker to today's date (without changing any date).

```
Me.DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
Me.DateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", Me.OrderdetailsBindingSource, "OrderDate", True))
Me.DateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.OrderdetailsBindingSource, "OrderDate", True))
Me.DateTimePicker1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10.2!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
Me.DateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
Me.DateTimePicker1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(158, 39)
Me.DateTimePicker1.Name = "DateTimePicker1"
Me.DateTimePicker1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(294, 28)
Me.DateTimePicker1.TabIndex = 2
Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = New Date(2019, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't have a DateTimePicker; it's a development tool. Presumably,  you're developing in either C# or VB.Net, using one of the GUI frameworks (Winforms, XAML, etc.). Which of those are you using? That information is needed in order to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry I am not a hardcore developer :) I am using VB.net with application type: windows forms application

Comment: Better. :-) Set the `Format` property to `Date`.

Comment: Whenever you store to Access, use `DateTimePicker.Value.Date` instead of `DateTimePicker.Value`. The [DateTime.Date property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8#System_DateTime_Date) will strip out any time information.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you  :) I see Four format option Long Short Time and custom. I have already selected custom and customFormat is set to dd-MM-yyyy however it is not helping

Comment: @djv in datetimepicker i have not selected any actions. it is having only data bindings to the access table. If user selects any date it picks up only date. However when user leave the datetimepicker value as it is (default todays date) it stores both date and time. What code should i write for no action on datetimepicker. or set default value as date

Comment: @GaneshParte it would help if you showed some code, particularly where the DateTimePicker value is bound to Access. Also, you should probably handle the time trimming on the other end - format it how you want when it is displayed.

Comment: @djv this is all i have - Me.DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
        Me.DateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Value", Me.OrderdetailsBindingSource, "OrderDate", True))
        Me.DateTimePicker1.DataBindings.Add(New System.Windows.Forms.Binding("Text", Me.OrderdetailsBindingSource, "OrderDate", True))
        Me.DateTimePicker1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 10.2!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
        Me.DateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom

Comment: OrderDetails is the table created in ms access

Comment: Rest of the code Me.DateTimePicker1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(158, 39)
        Me.DateTimePicker1.Name = "DateTimePicker1"
       Rest of the code  Me.DateTimePicker1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(294, 28)
        Me.DateTimePicker1.TabIndex = 2
        Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = New Date(2019, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: @djvI tried to change me.datetimepicker1.value.date however it gives me error "Expression is a value and therefore cannot be targeted for an assignment"

Comment: @GaneshParte I just added your code to the question. But in the future, as the asker, you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56741137/edit) your question to add any code even after the question is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access does not have a short date format such as SQL Server. See [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes.asp) for lists of data types.

**Access:**

- Date/Time,    Use for dates and times,    **8 bytes**

**SQL Server:**

- datetime, From January 1, 1753 to December 31, 9999 with an accuracy of 3.33 milliseconds,    **8 bytes**
- date, Store a date only. From January 1, 0001 to December 31, 9999,   **3 bytes**

So Access only has one date/time type which must be able to store time, which has the same number of bytes as SQL Server datetime. The date without a timestamp you see is actually 12 AM. This is what you are doing when you set the date/time on your DateTimePicker `Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = New Date(2019, 6, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0)`. This is incidentally your best solution, to set the DateTimePicker to today's date (just the date portion using the DateTime.Date property I menioned).

To solve your problem, do this in `Form_Load`:

```
Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Now.Date ' this makes it today at 12 AM
```

---

If you want to better understand what is going on, check out the value of your DateTimePicker at any time with this, to see that there is always a time in it, even if it's 12 AM:

```
MessageBox.Show($"{DateTimePicker1.Value:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}")
```

And run this query on your database to see that there is also always a time in an Access `Date/Time` field, and that Access automatically hides the time when it is 12 AM:

```sql
select 
orderdate
, format(orderdate, 'General Date') as GeneralDate
, format(orderdate, 'Short Time') as ShortTime
, format(orderdate, 'Medium Time') as MediumTime
, format(orderdate, 'Long Time') as LongTime
, format(orderdate, 'Short Date') as ShortDate
, format(orderdate, 'Medium Date') as MediumDate
, format(orderdate, 'Long Date') as LongDate
from orderdetails
```

Comment: Thank you djv. I have added following Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Today in form load event which is actually saving only date in the access database. However in my form I have add new button which actually resets all text box and allows users to add a new entry. Now if they dont select any date and leave date as todays date it again saves the date with time.     Private Sub BtnAddNew_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click
        OrderdetailsBindingSource.AddNew()
    End Sub

Comment: Again, it is not storing only the date in the database, rather it is storing the date with 12 AM as the time. Access is formatting it as date-only when the time is 12 AM. So you should also set `Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Today` in the button press it seems.

Comment: Thanks djv. This worked. I had added Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Today  this value before however it was before the OrderdetailsBindingSource.AddNew() function. I added this after the OrderdetailsBindingSource.AddNew() function and now i can see the date only. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, if I am not able to answer you perfectly in vb.net
i will give you an Answer in vb (how i mean it is correct)
and in correct c#

i understood that you want the code to save values in the database, if the date of the DateTimePicker is set today.

c#

```
if(dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == DateTime.Today)
{
    //insert your code here
}
```

vb.net

```
if dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == DateTime.Today
//Code here
end if
```

this if asks, if the picket Date of the DateTime is the same Date as today

if you just want to save the whole value of the date in the DataBase if the picked date is today so like: "25.06.2019 17:25" then you will have a problem.

If you save it as String you could format it:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy")
```

or

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("HH:mm")
```

so put the second in the "else" braket.

if you only need Date or time, you can format it like the above.

(sorry i am not sure if i understood your question right, so if it doesn't help you, just comment. I will answer)

Comment: Thank you LoaStaub. I just want to save only date not time in my access database. If I dont select any date by default it just saves date + time however if i select any date it saves only date. So i am just trying to figure out how to set the default value of datetimepicker to only date not time.

Comment: The confusion was in this sentence `I want to store the date only in the Access store when the user leaves the DateTimePicker to today's date`. It can be interpreted as `I want to store the date only, ... when the user leaves the DateTimePicker to today's date` or `I want to store the date, only ... when the user leaves the DateTimePicker to today's date`, the former reflecting the OP's actual intent.

Comment: Thanks LoaStaub. This is what I have done in my code Form load event   Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Today  and while adding a new entry to the database from the vb form.      Private Sub BtnAddNew_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddNew.Click
        OrderdetailsBindingSource.AddNew()
        Me.DateTimePicker1.Value = Date.Today
    End Sub